# Missing data means visualization not showing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bunch of nodes and links in my dataset.

All the links have a source and target attribute.

However, not all source and target nodes are in my nodes dataset.

Example :

```
nodes : {   
    'id' : 'A'
    },
    {   
    'id' : 'B'
    },
    {   
    'id' : 'C'
    };

links : {   
    'source' : 'A',
    'target' : 'B'
    },
    {   
    'source' : 'B',
    'target' : 'C'
    },
    {   
    'source' : 'C',
    'target' : 'D'
    }
```

Notice the last link links nodes 'C' and 'D' but I don't have a node with ID 'D'.

so i get the following error :

```
Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined
```

How to I go about not throwing the error if the source/target node can not be found and carry on displaying the force layout visualization ?

Comment: Could you show some of your code it is hard to say without seeing what you have written? thanks

Comment: Hey @Alex_B ive literally just solved it myself. I shall answer the question now to show you what the problem was. Thank you :)

Comment: That's great.  @thisOneGuy

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it myself. Basically, because the links were pointing at nodes that weren't even in the dataset I had to only use links that had both the source and target in the data.

Heres how  :

```
var edges = [];

links.forEach(function(e,i) { 

console.log(links.length)
    var sourceNode = nodes.filter(function(n) { return n.id === e.source; })[0],
    targetNode = nodes.filter(function(n) { return n.id === e.target; })[0];
if(sourceNode && targetNode){ //this is to make sure both the source and target node are not undefined
    edges.push({source: sourceNode, target: targetNode, origin : e.origin});
}
});
```

Basically, I had to make another array to use (edges) and populate that array with links that have both a source and a target node.

The check : `if(sourceNode && targetNode)` checks this. If they have, then they get added to the edges array which I then use with the force layout :)